# M1 MacBook can not execute python, after execute ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/local/python

Tags: python, macos, ln

```
luis@LuisdeMacBook-Pro ~ % python
zsh: command not found: python
luis@LuisdeMacBook-Pro ~ % ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
ln: /usr/local/bin/python: Permission denied
luis@LuisdeMacBook-Pro ~ % sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
luis@LuisdeMacBook-Pro ~ % python
python: error: Failed to locate 'python'.
xcode-select: Failed to locate 'python', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
```

python3 is ok, but every time execute above to ln -s, comes up below even installed success!
[image]

Comment: Have you tried typing `python3`, rather than `python`? Which is first in your $PATH, `/usr/bin/` or `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: python3 is ok, as below shows: Python 3.9.6 (default, Oct  1 2023, 17:38:10) 
[Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@did the trick:
sudo ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python

@see link:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/704099

@apple, xcode-select, GFY

Comment: Messing with the internals is probably a bad idea, especially since the proper workaround is extremely simple; use an alias, or put `#!/bin/sh` (newline) `exec python3 "$@"` in `/usr/local/bin/python`, make it executable with `chmod a+x` and go.